# use variable into Openwrt Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, openwrt

I would like to use variable into openwrt Makefile.am like following :

```
bin_PROGRAMS = TOTO

SOURCES =                               \
    ../src/cli.c                            \
    ../src/common.h                     \
    ../src/vendor/$(VENDOR)/common/vfile.h      \
    ../src/vendor/$(VENDOR)/common/vfile.c
```

in configure.ac file I define the variable :

```
VENDOR='IEEE'
AC_SUBST([VENDOR])
```

when build the openwrt package I got the following error :

```
Makefile:1212: ../src/vendor/IEEE/common/.deps/vfile.Po: No such file or directory
```

but under build_dir folder if got the file with the following path :

```
./src/vendor/$(VENDOR)/common/.deps/vfile.Po
```

what is wrong with the variable in the Makefile.am !!

Comment: `AC_SUBST` substitutes tokens like `@...@` in your .in file.  It doesn't automatically create makefile variables.  Do you have a `@VENDOR@` anywhere in your `Makefile.am`, say something like `VENDOR = @VENDOR@`?

Comment: yes I have variable in Makefile.in : : VENDOR = @VENDOR@

Comment: Sorry but you'll have to debug this.  What is in your generated Makefile at line 1212?  Note, the path that is missing starts with `../src` while the path you show above is `./src`... maybe there's an extra `.` in your `Makefile.am` somewhere?

Comment: the problem is : the folder IEEE doesn't created and the folder $(VENDOR) is created instead, then the vfile.Po will not be found at this path  : /src/vendor/IEEE/common/.deps/vfile.Po

Answer (score 0):

this configuration will fix the issue :

```
bin_PROGRAMS = TOTO

SOURCES =                               \
    ../src/cli.c                            \
    ../src/common.h                     \
    ../src/vendor/@VENDOR@/common/vfile.h      \
    ../src/vendor/@VENDOR@/common/vfile.c
```